# Fazer uma WHILE rodar a partir do click de um botão

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Tenho um formulário que deve preenchido de forma automática. Mas esse preenchimento depende de uma escolha do usuário, então deve ser executado depois da escolha, acredito que um botão seria o ideal.

Para exemplificar:
Tenho várias montadoras de carro (Volkswagen, Ford, Peugeot). O usuário irá escolher qual montadora deseja em um campo drop down. Conforme sua escolha, um formulário deve ser preenchido de forma "automática" com todos os carros dessa montadora (cadastrados no BD). Por exemplo: Escolheu Volkswagen no meno drop down, então o formulário deve ser preenchido com os veículos Parati, Gol, Santana...

Eu fiz um "while" que traz todos os medicamentos de um determinado grupo de medicamentos. Porém não traz nenhum resultado por que é executado quando a página abre. Preciso criar um "botão" ou uma forma de ser executado só depois de que o usuário escolher o tipo de grupo de medicamentos, para aí sim meu while rodar e preencher todo o formulário.

Segue o While:

```
        while (($exibe = oci_fetch_array($parsed_medicamento_s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
                                                $DS_MATERIAL                = $exibe ['DS_MATERIAL'];
                                                $DS_VIA_APLICACAO           = $exibe ['DS_VIA_APLICACAO'];
                                                $QT_DOSE                    = $exibe ['QT_DOSE'];
                                                $DS_INTERVALO               = $exibe ['DS_INTERVALO'];
                                                $CD_UNIDADE_MEDIDA          = $exibe ['CD_UNIDADE_MEDIDA'];
                                                $DS_DIAS_APLICACAO          = $exibe ['DS_DIAS_APLICACAO'];
                                                $DS_CICLOS_APLICACAO        = $exibe ['DS_CICLOS_APLICACAO'];
                                                $DILUICAO_RECONSTITUINTE    = $exibe ['DILUICAO_RECONSTITUINTE'];
                                                $DS_RECONSTITUINTE          = $exibe ['DS_RECONSTITUINTE'];
                                                $UNID_MED_RECONSTITUINTE    = $exibe ['UNID_MED_RECONSTITUINTE'];
                                                $DS_DILUINTE                = $exibe ['DS_DILUINTE'];
                                                $QT_DOSE_DILUENTE           = $exibe ['QT_DOSE_DILUENTE'];
                                                $CD_UNIDADE_MEDIDA_DILUENTE = $exibe ['CD_UNIDADE_MEDIDA_DILUENTE'];

    echo '<div class="tbline"><div class="tbcel1 excluir"><a href="?exclui=ok&id='.$idsession.'&nr_sequencia='.$NR_SEQUENCIA.'"><font color="#FFFFFF">excluir</font></a></div><div class="tbcel3">'.$DS_MATERIAL.'</div><div class="tbcel2">'.$DS_VIA_APLICACAO.'</div><div class="tbcel2">'.$QT_DOSE.'</div><div class="tbcel2">'.$DS_UNIDADE_MEDIDA.'</div><div class="tbcel3">'.$DS_DIAS_APLICACAO.'</div><div class="tbcel3">'.$DS_CICLOS_APLICACAO.'</div><div class="tbcel3">'.$DS_DILUENTE.'</div><div class="tbcel2">'.$QT_DOSE_DILUENTE.'</div><div class="tbcel2">'.$DS_UNID_MEDIDA_DILUENTE.'</div></div>';
```

Segue onde o usuário escolhe o tipo de grupo de medicamento, nomeado protocolo:

```
                               <div class="label">
                                <label>Protocolo</label><br />
                                <select name="protocolo" id="protocolo" class="protocolo input">
                                <option selected="selected" value="selecione">--- Selecione uma opção ---</option>
                                <?php
                                while (($exibe = oci_fetch_array($parsed_prot, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
                                                                        $CD_PROTOCOLO   = $exibe ['CD_PROTOCOLO'];  
                                                                        $NM_PROTOCOLO   = $exibe ['NM_PROTOCOLO'];
                                echo '<option value="'.$CD_PROTOCOLO.'">'.$NM_PROTOCOLO.'</option>';
                                } ?>
                                </select> 
                                </div>
```

Só depois dessa escolha, o while deve ser executado.

Comment: Posta o código que estás utilizando pra isso.

Comment: Editado. Agora com o código.

Comment: Voce tem N maneiras de fazer isso. 

 Voce pode carregar todos os modelos na pagina e ocultar utilizando divs. Apos selecionar a montadora, voce exibe apenas a div correspondente.

ou ( recomendado )

Voce pode carregar os modelos utilizando ajax

Comment: Inviável carregar todos os modelos. São mais de 10.000 registros. Como eu poderia utilizar o Ajax?

Comment: São mais de 10.000 registros e aí eles vem paginados, não?  Ainda assim teria problema? Qnto ao ajax, pode fazer uma requisição pra uma página que retorne pra voce essas informações só quando clicada na opção que tu quer...

Comment: Cara, só AJAX! Esquece o restante.